# VNC Server API's for iOS Apps

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to develop an iPhone app that will run in background as a VNC server. Kindly suggest me what private API's I should use. I am not developing this app for App Store so I think I can use some private API's for this.

I don't want to Jail Break also due to some reasons.

Kindly suggest me what API's, concepts I should implement.

Comment: Veency won't work on ios8 is there another alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Veency.  They use a rooted / jailbroken IOS and it should give you a starting point. Its under Cydia, but it doesn't work on IOS 6.  Just fyi.

Comment: The OP wants to make something like Veency, not find something like it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any 'API' for that; maybe you can start looking at 'airplay' api's instead.